# Searching for object which has attribute ~ roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently working on making a game in roblox, for the game I have to find all children in a folder called blocks which have the custom attribute: Selected, and I want Selected to be true (it's a boolean so the attribute has to be true). I've searched trough the roblox api and devforum but I couldn't find any solutions to this problem. So if you know a way how to do this, I would really appreciate if you could tell me

Comment: Instead of using [Instance attributes](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/instance-attributes), I would recommend CollectionService Tags. [CollectionService:GetTagged](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/CollectionService/GetTagged) returns a table of every object that has a specific tag.

Comment: I didn't get the tags to work, but I worked my way around all of it by storing the last target and then checking the values on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through that folder and try to get the ones that have that attribute by using an if statement and putting them in an array.

```lua
local selectedBlocks = {}

for _, block in ipairs(folder:GetChildren()) do
    if block:GetAttribute("Selected") ~= nil then
        table.insert(selectedBlocks, block)
    end
end
```